# Display specific line or record of a recordset

Tags: php

Say I have a recordset, lets call it $rsRecordset. Now lets say it has data in it like so:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Now I want to display, for example, the 5. How might I do that? I've read a lot about something that seems to be structured like so:

```
echo $rsRecordset[1][1];
```

But for the life of me I can't make it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($rsRecordset);` for us?

Comment: Hmmm, it was a hypothetical one, lol, lemme go make a real one and var_dumb it :)

Comment: recordset - as in a result handle from a database call? Or just some array?

Comment: Thats the one, the result handle of a database call

Comment: A result from a database call is usually a resource you have yet to get the data out of. Depending on the database / package used there are different answers.

Comment: The answer that was just deleted seemed to be on the right track...  but mysql_result($rsRecordset, 0) displayed 1, mysql_result($rsRecordset, 1) displayed 2, mysql_result($rsRecordset, 2) displayed 3, but mysql_result($rsRecordset, 3) and onward didn't display anything? Do I need a second number for the row?

Comment: <?php echo mysql_result($rsRecordset, 1, 2); ?>

Thats the boy :)

If the person who originally answered that wants to post it again I'll give them the tick...

Comment: That was [JK](http://stackoverflow.com/users/286390/jk) btw. On to bigger questions: if you only need that result, why does your query generate more rows & columns then needed?

Comment: Because I want the others in different parts of the page :). I don't want them in a table format (which would be easily doable via a loop).

Comment: Note that the old mysql extension is on its way to deprecation. With mysqli, you can write a function that calls [`mysqli_result::data_seek`](http://php.net/mysqli_result.data_seek) to select a particular row and [`mysqli_result::fetch_row`](http://php.net/mysqli_result.fetch_row) to get the row as an array, which it can then index to get the field. No matter the extension, accessing rows this way will impact performance and memory usage. Better is to limit the SQL statement to fetch only the data you need and process the rows serially. Why do you need to access the data one field at a time?

Comment: Because I need to position my data in a particular way. If I need say a random three rows from my table, and want to display them in an unloopable way, surely calling all three rows and letting PHP sort out the data is a much better way then running three individual querys?

Comment: @Ferdia: That doesn't answer my question. What is the "particular way"? Regarding random access, relational tables are unordered (hence random access) unless you specify an ordering. You don't need to access result rows in a loop, you can use a fetch function to get the next row when it's time to process it.  There's no need for separate queries; your question presents a false dichotomy. Why can't you execute a query that returns the results you need, and only the results you need?

Comment: I have executed a query that returns the results I need, and only the results I need. I need rows from a table, ordered by rand() and limited to 3. I then need to use all three columns, in a way that doesnt allow me to simple run a do loop to structure the data. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question :|

Comment: I think I just figured out what you're asking. I only asked how to get the 5 as a hypothetical. I need all 9 pieces of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JK hasn't returned, I guess I'm answering this myself.

The following was the boy:

```
<?php echo mysql_result($rsRecordset, 1, 2); ?>
```

Again, if JK returns I will happily give him the tick. If not I'll apply it to myself tomorrow, since it was technically a joint effort anyway.

Comment: Ok, no sign of JK so I get the tick I suppose.